# How to run Controller function using SSH

Tags: magento-1.9, product, controllers, ssh

I have function **massProductcreateAction()** At

> app\code\local\Adit\Rapnet\controllers\Adminhtml\RapnetController.php

This function creates product from database and after creating 30 product to Magento, script will be time out.(500: Internal Error)

So is there a way to continuously run this function and I can create 10000 item at a single time. Using SSH or cron?

Comment: did you find any way to do this? I also have the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

You may try the below command in your ssh like

> nohup php your_controller_url &

the above command will run in background until the process complete.

Comment: site url is http://privosa.com/
And path is app\code\local\Adit\Rapnet\controllers\Adminhtml\RapnetController.php
And Function is massProductcreateAction().
can you please let me know that is "your_controller_url "

Comment: you can't run it from admin. you can try the code file from root folder or else through using frontend controller.